# Grafana Bar chart based on SQL with 2 items in GROUP BY

Tags: grafana

My Grafana bar chart is based on Postgres SQL:

```
select the_date, name, max(value) as max_value
from T
where the_date >= DATE(‘2023-08-01T07:00:00Z’) and the_date <= DATE(‘2023-09-01T06:59:59Z’)
group by the_date, name
order by the_date, name
```

In Bar chart properties I specified X-Axis as “the_date”.
In Postgres table the “the_date” column has type “DATE”.

**Problem #1**: currently the bar chart shows the x-axis labels as several identical values:

17:00:00.000 17:00:00.000 17:00:00.000 17:00:00.000 17:00:00.000

But I want to show on X-axis the dates in format MM-DD, for example:

```
08-01 08-02 08-03 08-04 08-05
```

**Problem #2**: Currently every bar has his own X-axis label.

I need all bars for the same date to be under the single/common X-axis label.

Comment: Feels like you need not a bar chart, but Time series panel with style set to Bars.